# Is there a way to use presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams with initial text?

Tags: ios, facebook

Is there a way to use presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams on Facebook SDK iOS with initial text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Prefilling the user message in any way is against Facebook's Platform Policies. See section 2.3 of https://developers.facebook.com/policy